# Can menus in Vim be made "dynamic"?

Tags: vim

i.e. to show a value (let's say, for the purpose of this example, `set tabstop?` ... `8`), but when that value changes to show the changed value?

I'm playing with Vim to see if I could setup a menu which would display some of my more used settings to save up on `set setting?` ... any ideas?

Comment: I think you might want to do this in the statusline rather than in a menu. I use the menu bar to keep track of what mode I am in and several other settings. You might want to check the source for powerline, https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline, for ideas

Comment: @GeoffLanotte - No, no, ... I didn't mix the two up. The question stands. My statusline is for something else. Btw, you use the menu to track what mode you're in? Isn't that a bit strange?

Comment: @GeoffLanotte - Btw, I know of powerline plugin but it doesn't work for me for some special reasons (utf8 problems which vim has some problems with).

Comment: I figured, that is why I commented. Wish I could help, bust of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also find it a little bit unusual to put settings values into the menu (a menu item usually is associated with an action that is triggered by selecting it), and would also recommend using either the `'statusline'` (for settings that you want to see in parallel for each open buffer) or `'titlestring'` (for settings that you only need for the current buffer).

You can use the `:menu` and `:unmenu` command to dynamically create and update menu items. Unlike the above mentioned mechanisms, however, Vim will not automatically trigger the updates; you have to do this with `:autocmd`s on the appropriate events (e.g. `CursorHold`) yourself.

Comment: I prefer using statusline for the file related settings (encoding, line & column numbers, word count etc.) and would like to use the menu values for those things that are buffer related like (shiftwidth, tabsize etc.)